# r - find maximum length "chain" of numerically increasing pairs of numbers

Tags: r

I have a two column dataframe of number pairs:

```
ODD <- c(1,1,1,3,3,3,5,7,7,9,9)
EVEN <- c(10,8,2,2,6,4,2,6,8,4,8)

dfPairs <- data.frame(ODD, EVEN)

> dfPairs
   ODD EVEN
1    1   10
2    1    8
3    1    2
4    3    2
5    3    6
6    3    4
7    5    2
8    7    6
9    7    8
10   9    4
11   9    8
```

Each row of this dataframe is a pair of numbers, and I would like to a find the longest possible numerically increasing combination of pairs. Conceptually, this is analogous to making a chain link of number pairs; with the added conditions that 1) links can only be formed using the same number and 2) the final chain must increase numerically. Visually, the program I am looking for will accomplish this:

[image]

For instance, row three is pair (1,2), which increases left to right. The next link in the chain would need to have a 2 in the EVEN column and increase right to left, such as row four (3,2). Then the pattern repeats, so the next link would need to have a 3 in the ODD column, and increase left to right, such as rows 5 or 6. The chain doesn't have to start at 1, or end at 9 - this was simply a convenient example.

If you try to make all possible linked pairs, you will find that many unique chains of various lengths are possible. I would like to find the longest possible chain. In my real data, I will likely encounter a situation in which more than one chain tie for the longest, in which case I would like all of these returned.

The final result should return the longest possible chain that meets these requirements as a dataframe, or a list of dataframes if more than one solution is possible, containing only the rows in the chain.

Thanks in advance. This one has been perplexing me all morning.

Comment: Wouldn't the "chain" 1->8 (row 2) 9<-8 (row11) be longer, at least in the sense of spanning more rows? Seems at the moment that there is a lot of ambiguity in hte question. Also there is no "motivation" or contaxt to guide us in determining what additional rules to apply.

Comment: @42-, technically yes, but this is not the question. I want to most number of links, ie pairs, possible in a chain.

Comment: Well as the rest of my comment implied, it was fairly hard to determine what _was_ the question.

Comment: @42-, sorry about that. Im looking for the longest chain denoted by greatest number of links. Not the longest chain denoted by longest links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited to deal with df that does not start at 1 and returns maximum chains rather than chain lengths*

Take advantage of graph data structure using `igraph`

Your data, `dfPairs`

```
ODD <- c(1,1,1,3,3,3,5,7,7,9,9)
EVEN <- c(10,8,2,2,6,4,2,6,8,4,8)
dfPairs <- data.frame(ODD, EVEN)
```

New data, `dfTest`

```
ODD <- c(3,3,3,5,7,7,9,9)
EVEN <- c(2,6,4,2,6,8,4,8)
dfTest <- data.frame(ODD, EVEN)
```

Make graph of your data. A key to my solution is to `rbind` the reverse (`rev(dfPairs)`) of the data frame to the original data frame. This will allow for building directional edges from odd numbers to even numbers. Graphs can be used to construct directional paths fairly easily.

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
GPairs <- graph_from_data_frame(dplyr::arrange(rbind(setNames(dfPairs, c("X1", "X2")), setNames(rev(dfPairs), c("X1", "X2"))), X1))
GTest <- graph_from_data_frame(dplyr::arrange(rbind(setNames(dfTest, c("X1", "X2")), setNames(rev(dfTest), c("X1", "X2"))), X1))
```

Here's the first three elements of `all_simple_paths(GPairs, 1)` (starting at 1)

```
[[1]]
+ 2/10 vertices, named, from f8e4f01:
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
+ 3/10 vertices, named, from f8e4f01:
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
+ 4/10 vertices, named, from f8e4f01:
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

I create a function to 1) convert all simple paths to list of numeric vectors, 2) filter each numeric vector for only elements that satisfy left->right increasing, and 3) return the maximum chain of left->right increasing numeric vector

```
max_chain_only_increasing <- function(gpath) {
                            list_vec <- lapply(gpath, function(v) as.numeric(names(unclass(v))))    # convert to list of numeric vector
                            only_increasing <- lapply(list_vec, function(v) v[1:min(which(v >= dplyr::lead(v, default=tail(v, 1))))])   # subset vector for only elements that are left->right increasing
                            return(unique(only_increasing[lengths(only_increasing) == max(lengths(only_increasing))]))                     # return maximum chain length
                        }
```

This is the output of the above function using all paths that start from 1

```
max_chain_only_increasing(all_simple_paths(GPairs, 1))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 6 7 8 9
```

Now, I'll output (header) of max chains starting with each unique element in `dfPairs`, your original data

```
start_vals <- sort(unique(unlist(dfPairs)))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
max_chains <- sapply(seq_len(length(start_vals)), function(i) max_chain_only_increasing(all_simple_paths(GPairs, i)))
names(max_chains) <- start_vals
# $`1`
# [1] 1 2 3 6 7 8 9

# $`2`
# [1] 2 3 6 7 8 9

# $`3`
# [1] 3 6 7 8 9

# $`4`
# [1] 4 9

# $`5`
# [1] 5
# etc
```

And finally with `dfTest`, the newer data

```
start_vals <- sort(unique(unlist(dfTest)))
max_chains <- sapply(seq_len(length(start_vals)), function(i) max_chain_only_increasing(all_simple_paths(GTest, i)))
names(max_chains) <- start_vals
# $`2`
# [1] 2 3 6 7 8 9

# $`3`
# [1] 3 6 7 8 9

# $`4`
# [1] 4 9

# $`5`
# [1] 5

# $`6`
# [1] 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Where is the final dataframe stored that contains the links for the longest chain?

Comment: I commented-out the line beginning with "return" in your max_chainlength_only_increasing function, which then returned the list of vectors containing the links named max_chainlengths. I can work with this. Brilliant. Many thanks.

Comment: Correction in my last comment. Its actually a list of lists. The first list is the list of starting points. Each of the starting points has a list of possible vectors that can be created from that point.

Comment: Another very pertinent point is that the max_chainlength_only_increasing function only works when starting from 1. If you remove the first three pairs in my example data, you will get an "Invalid starting vector" error. Make sure you modify your data accordingly.

Comment: In spite of my efforts...lulz

Comment: I appreciate the update to your answer, I can get this to work now. While I'm probably going to continue using my own solution below, the introduction to igraph and your workflow are very useful. It helps my overall thinking and approach to programming. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of Cpak's efforts I ended up writing my own function to solve this. In essence I realize I could make the right to left chain links left to right by using this section of code from Cpak's answer:

```
output <- arrange(rbind(setNames(dfPairs, c("X1", "X2")), setNames(rev(dfPairs), c("X1", "X2")))`, X1)
```

To ensure the resulting chains were sequential, I deleted all decreasing links:

```
output$increase <- with(output, ifelse(X2>X1, "Greater", "Less"))
output <- filter(output, increase == "Greater")
output <- select(output, -increase)
```

I realized that if I split the dataframe output by unique values in X1, I could join each of these dataframes sequentially by joining the last column of the first dataframe to the first column of the next dataframe, which would create rows of sequentially increasing chains. The only problem I needed to resolve was the issues of NAs in last column of the mered dataframe. So ended up splitting the joined dataframe after each merge, and then shifted the dataframe to remove the NAs, and rbinded the result back together.

This is the actual code:

```
out_split <- split(output, output$X1)
df_final <-  Reduce(join_shift, out_split)
```

The function, join_shift, is this:

```
join_shift <- function(dtf1,dtf2){
  abcd <- full_join(dtf1, dtf2, setNames(colnames(dtf2)[1], colnames(dtf1)[ncol(dtf1)]))
  abcd[is.na(abcd)]<-0
  colnames(abcd)[ncol(abcd)] <- "end"
  # print(abcd)
  abcd_na <- filter(abcd, end==0)
  # print(abcd_na)
  abcd <- filter(abcd, end != 0)
  abcd_na <- abcd_na[moveme(names(abcd_na), "end first")]
  # print(abcd_na)

  names(abcd_na) <- names(abcd)
  abcd<- rbind(abcd, abcd_na)
  z <- length(colnames(abcd))
  colnames(abcd)<- c(paste0("X", 1:z))
  # print(abcd)
  return(abcd)

}
```

Finally, I found there were a lot of columns that had only zeros in it, so I wrote this to delete them and trim the final dataframe:

```
df_final_trim = df_final[,colSums(df_final) > 0]
```

Overall Im happy with this. I imagine it could be a little more elegant, but it works on anything, and it works on some rather huge, and complicated data. This will produce ~ 241,700 solutions from a dataset of 700 pairs.

I also used a moveme function that I found on stackoverflow (see below). I employed it to move NA values around to achieve the shift aspect of the join_shift function.

```
moveme <- function (invec, movecommand) {
  movecommand <- lapply(strsplit(strsplit(movecommand, ";")[[1]], 
                                 ",|\\s+"), function(x) x[x != ""])
  movelist <- lapply(movecommand, function(x) {
    Where <- x[which(x %in% c("before", "after", "first", 
                              "last")):length(x)]
    ToMove <- setdiff(x, Where)
    list(ToMove, Where)
  })
  myVec <- invec
  for (i in seq_along(movelist)) {
    temp <- setdiff(myVec, movelist[[i]][[1]])
    A <- movelist[[i]][[2]][1]
    if (A %in% c("before", "after")) {
      ba <- movelist[[i]][[2]][2]
      if (A == "before") {
        after <- match(ba, temp) - 1
      }
      else if (A == "after") {
        after <- match(ba, temp)
      }
    }
    else if (A == "first") {
      after <- 0
    }
    else if (A == "last") {
      after <- length(myVec)
    }
    myVec <- append(temp, values = movelist[[i]][[1]], after = after)
  }
  myVec
}
```